# How to change material name (batch) to the name of its texture?

Tags: materials, uv

Any way to make multiple materials use the same name as its texture?

Like if a texture was named "ref32.png" but the material name was "88" how would I batch name multiple materials to be their texture name?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46795/is-there-a-quick-way-to-copy-the-object-name-to-the-mesh-data-name/

Comment: thats for naming the object, i mean changing the material name to the texture name

Comment: The linked addon has tools to rename many datablocks, including materials. Whether it can do what you want or not is another matter. Since a material can have many textures there isn't necessarily a one to one correlation to use for renaming